# Is there a way in a VCS to have a child branch that only syncs a few specific folders/files from the parent?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

Lets say I have repository for a project that has a bunch of folders and files lets call it master.

- /3rdPartyJars
- /compass
- /js
- /deploy
- /js
- /python
- build.xml

When I deploy to the production server I just want to push the latest deploy and python folders to the server.  Previously I was using svn1.7 and I just created a deploy repository that when a deploy would happen I would just drop the latest folders in and commit to the deploy repository and do an update from the server.

I think a better approach would be to have a deploy branch created from master which only has the two folders.  When deploy would be needed the only a sync from master would need to be done.  Is there a way to do this with branching in git or another vcs?  Keep in mind I am still very new to git and I have only used it in my free time for about a couple of weeks now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend just deploying your master branch on the server. If it is important to you that only those two folders are created, you can achieve that by doing a sparse checkout. See my answer here: [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only/13738951#13738951)